# Protouf parsing (C3 and C2 added)

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, reverse-engineering, whatsapp

I'm trying to parse some whatsapp data serialized but during the process the is some C2 and C3 added.
For example the string : 
F0-9F-8F-B3-E2-80-8D-F0-9F-8C-88 
Is transformed in : 
C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8F-C2-B3-C3-A2-C2-80-C2-8D-C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8C-C2-88

We can see also that the F0 -> B0 and the E2 -> A2.
These tranformation only happend with the C3 bytes

Moreover the C2 and C3 bytes are not counted on the size.
I really don't know what these bytes are representing, does anyone has a clue ?

The orginal message part look like this : 
12-0D-0A-0B-C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8F-C2-B3-C3-A2-C2-80-C2-8D-C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8C-C2-88

**Edit**
The data are comming from whatsapp-web web-socket, they are decrypted and then parsed with protobuf. The main issue is that the datas comming from whatsapp-web are not proper protobuf datas (I was trying to parse them with this website https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode). But if the C2 are remove and in general the upper modifications are applied the message deserialize correctly. One more thing that I noticed is that it only apply for long messages and messages with smiley.
This is a whole message (in hex and different from the upper one):
0A-40-0A-1A-30-30-30-30-30-30-30-30-30-30-30-40-73-2E-77-68-61-74-73-61-70-70-2E-6E-65-74-10-00-1A-20-20-21-22-23-24-25-26-27-28-29-30-31-32-33-34-35-36-37-38-39-40-41-42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49-50-51-12-0D-0A-0B-C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8F-C2-B3-C3-A2-C2-80-C2-8D-C3-B0-C2-9F-C2-8C-C2-88-18-C3-A3-C2-A0-C3-9B-C3-B6-05-20-00

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with protocol-buffers (which is a specific format) - can you clarify whether you meant that specifically, or whether you're just asking about data protocols in general?

Comment: I edited the post to add some more explanations

Comment: Ok, context helps. They're definitely doing something very ... awkward there. I've eyeballed it a few times, and whatever they're doing isn't obvious to me. It *looks* like the C3 is mostly used with higher bytes - maybe something to do with avoiding the MSB for ASCII reasons, but then there's a confusion because f0 -> c3b0 at th start, but b0 -> c3b0 later, so ... two inputs give the same output. Which is... confusing!

Comment: Well it seems indeed it was an escaping problem ! There was an issue in the original post, actually the B0 was a F0 too. The C2 escaped all characters with code > 127 and < 192 leaved unmodified while C3 escapes all characters with code above 192 (with 2nd bit set). And C3 was putting the 64 weight bit to 0. It was indeed to avoid having the MSB because there was a custom protocol wrapping the protobuf messages using tags with 2 first bit set for each tag. Thank you very much for your help, that helped a lot !

Comment: k, knowing there was a transcription error helps :) do you still need any help here?